# Error "function count_if() could not be resolved" - C++

Tags: c++, eclipse, c++11, lambda

I am using Eclipse for C++ testing and I am getting an error related to the `count_if()` function.
Here is my code:

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include  <vector>

   using namespace std;

   int main(){

   vector<int> v{3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,100,12,2};
   auto isodd=[](int x){return x % 2;};

   std::count_if(begin(v),end(v),isodd(3));

   return 0;
 }
```

While compiling this program Eclipse gives the following error: "function count_if() could not be resolved".

Thanks for any kind of hint.

Comment: Start by adding `#include <algorithm>` somewhere close to the top of the file.

Comment: thanks @JerryCoffin .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done very silly mistake.By adding

```
 #include < algorithm>
```

I've solved my problem.

Comment: hi @W.K.S i've solved this by the help of Jerry Coffin.